# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "type"

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, jpa

This is my code which executes two methods:

```
<h:panelGroup> <br /><br />  
    <h:outputLabel id="yearLbl" value="Year:" />
    <h:outputLabel id="selectType" /><br />
    <h:selectOneMenu id="type" value="#{clController.type}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="2013" itemLabel="2013" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="2012" itemLabel="2012" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="2011" itemLabel="2011" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="2010" itemLabel="2010" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="2009" itemLabel="2009" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="2008" itemLabel="2008" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:commandButton type="submit" onclick="#{clController.getTotal(clController.type)}" action="#{clController.getPaymentByMonth(clController.type)}"  id="stateInfo"  value="Show Monthly "  >              
    </h:commandButton>
</h:panelGroup>
```

These are the functions called:

```
public DataModel getPaymentByMonth(String year) {            
    this.session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

    List<CustomerPayment> paymentList = null;
    try {
        org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Query q = session.createQuery("from CustomerPayment where DATE like '%" + year + "'");
        paymentList = (List<CustomerPayment>) q.list();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return paymentDataModel = new ListDataModel(paymentList);    
}

public DataModel getTotal(String year) {
    this.session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

    List<CustomerPayment> total = null;
    try {
        org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        System.out.println(year);
        Query q = session.createQuery("select c.type, c.date, sum(c.amount) from CustomerPayment c  where c.date  LIKE '%"+year+"' group by c.type");
        System.out.println("select c.type, c.date, sum(c.amount) from CustomerPayment c  where c.date  LIKE '%"+year+"' group by c.type");
        total = (List<CustomerPayment>) q.list();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return totalDataTable = new ListDataModel(total);    
}
```

The problem is that i get this error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "type"
```

The type means years but i gives error with that. When i print type into screen it prints for ex 2013 why i get this error?

Full stack trace:

```
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:514)
    at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.coerce(ArrayELResolver.java:166)
    at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:46)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstDeferredExpression.getValue(AstDeferredExpression.java:44)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstCompositeExpression.getValue(AstCompositeExpression.java:50)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.OutputLinkRenderer.encodeChildren(OutputLinkRenderer.java:124)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.renderRow(TableRenderer.java:385)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeChildren(TableRenderer.java:162)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:424)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Comment: yes, the full stacktrace will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "type"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:514)
    at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.coerce(ArrayELResolver.java:166)
    at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:46)
```

The exception is telling that you're attempting to access an array in EL using a non-integer index `type`, something like this in raw Java code:

```
Object[] array = getItSomehow();
array["type"];
```

This is obviously wrong. The stack trace hints that you've a

```html
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.customerPayments}" var="customerPayment">
    ...
    <h:inputText value="#{customerPayment.type}" />
```

The exception itself hints that `customerPayments` is a `List<Object[]>` and not a `List<CustomerPayment>` in contrary to what you expected and (incorrectly!!) downcasted. You're not selecting `c` as in `SELECT c FROM CustomerPayment c`, but only the individual properties, so every record is represented as `Object[]`.

One of the solutions would be to stick to `List<Object>` and use indexes instead of propertynames to access them. You selected `c.type` as 1st column, so it has array index `0`:

```html
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.customerPayments}" var="customerPayment">
    ...
    <h:inputText value="#{customerPayment[0]}" />
```

Answer (score -1):

are you sure there are no tailing white spaces or leading white spaces

```
new Integer("2013") - Woks
new Integer(" 2013") - will not work
```

Comment: This isn't going to be the problem - it is clear from the exception that the system is trying to parse the string `"type"` as a number (and, unsurprisingly, failing).

Answer (score -1):

ok, let's analyze something. according to the full stack trace.

this error came from render phase.

```
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
```

so it occurred after action method call.

and this error was thrown when the some child component in OutputLink trying to encode value(render value)

```
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.OutputLinkRenderer.encodeChildren(OutputLinkRenderer.java:124)
```

and the OutputLink seem living in some Table.

```
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.renderRow(TableRenderer.java:385)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeChildren(TableRenderer.java:162)
```

so, you should check some link in a table which is at other place of your layout file.