# JSF datatable columns from multiple database tables

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, nhibernate, jsf-2

I have a JSF datatable, it has three columns, those are:Work_Type_Desc, Project_Phase, and Activity_Desc. Those columns comes from 2 different database tables, the relationship of those two tables are one-to-many.

The 1st Table name is Work_Type. It has 1) Work_Type_Cd, 2)Work_Type_Desc, 3)Created_By_Name, 4)Created_DT, 5)Updated_By_Name, 6) Updated_DT

The 2nd Table name is Activity_Type. It has 1)Activity_Cd,2) Work_Type_Cd,3)Project_Phase,4)Activity_Desc, 5)Created_By_Name, 6)Created_DT, 7)Updated_By_Name, 8) Updated_DT.

I use Hibernate+Spring+JSF, my question is how to show those three column records in JSF datatable, do I need to create a new model domain class to store this two tables properties? If so, how to handle the PK and FK in the new model class. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just let your service layer return a `List<ActivityType>`. The `WorkType` is already referenced by `@ManyToOne` property in `ActivityType`, right?

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.activityTypes}" var="activityType">
    <h:column>#{activityType.workType.workTypeDesc}</h:column>
    <h:column>#{activityType.projectPhase}</h:column>
    <h:column>#{activityType.activityDesc}</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

It's generally unnecessary to create another mapping layer for that.

Comment: Thanks for ur help!Balus. I tried ur way, it still doesn't work. And I already set the one to many mapping in cfg file. I just return List<ActivityType> as return type in DAO layer, and all this method in service layer, in JSF page, I followed ur above advice. Could you specify the solution? Thanks! Much appreciated.

Comment: Please elaborate "doesn't work" in developer's perspective instead of enduser's perspective. You are not giving *any* clue as to what and how exactly it failed.

Comment: Thanks for ur response. When I opened the page, the error is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "workType"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:449)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
 at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.toInteger(ArrayELResolver.java:375)
 at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:195)
It seems that JSF cannot get workType using <h:outputText value="#{item.workType.work_Type_Desc}"></h:outputText>

Comment: Apparently `activityTypes` is not a `List<ActivityType>`, but a `List<Object[]>`. Fix your JPA query. This is not a JSF problem. It was just being supplied the wrong model by JPA.

Comment: Thanks! Balus. This is my hql: from ActivityType as at inner join at.workType, I put the return type as List<ActivityType>, and keep other things. Still got the above error. Do u know why? Thanks!

Comment: Generics are compile time syntactic sugar. JPA fills the list by reflection. Try in your own Java backing bean code `for (ActivityType activityType : activityTypes) {...}` you'll see that it throws a class cast exception because the list actually holds `Object[]` instances. JSF is facing exactly this same problem because it is seeing an `Object[]` and thus expecting an integer index like `0` to obtain the item, but instead you supplied a string `"workType"`.

Comment: Related answer to your new problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317431/java-lang-numberformatexception-for-input-string-type/16329086#16329086

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I already figure it out after seeing the link u showed me. Thank you!!!

Comment: Will do. Thanks! One more question, for the datatable I need above, I can do get all existing records and add records now, but still have problem when delete and update, could u please give me hints? Thanks again!

Comment: Sure, just press "Ask Question" button on right top and post the question along with the necessary information in order to understand and reproduce the problem and provide an answer.

Comment: Thanks! Please see my new post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541993/delete-jsf-database-rowcolumns-in-row-from-different-database