# Delete JSF Datatable row(columns in row from different database)

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, jsf-2, hibernate-mapping

I have a JSF datatable, it has three columns, those are:Work_Type_Desc, Project_Phase, and Activity_Desc. Those columns comes from 2 different database tables, the relationship of those two tables are one-to-many.

The 1st Table name is Work_Type. It has 1) Work_Type_Cd, 2)Work_Type_Desc, 3)Created_By_Name, 4)Created_DT, 5)Updated_By_Name, 6) Updated_DT

The 2nd Table name is Activity_Type. It has 1)Activity_Cd,2) Work_Type_Cd,3)Project_Phase,4)Activity_Desc, 5)Created_By_Name, 6)Created_DT, 7)Updated_By_Name, 8) Updated_DT.

I use Hibernate+Spring+JSF, my previous question was how to show those three column records in JSF datatable, it has been solved with the help of a nice guy here,
 [JSF datatable columns from multiple database tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519131/jsf-datatable-columns-from-multiple-database-tables).

Now, I have a new question, I can show all the existing records and add new records in JSF pages now. But have problem when delete and update.Here is my delete code, I already set the cascade as all, because I need to do all CRUD:

adminService.deleteActivity((String[]) dataTable.getRowData());
allActivities = adminService.findAllActivityTypes();

But it doesn't work, do you know how to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: Please elaborate "doesn't work" in developer's terms. What exactly happens (not)? Is the JSF bean action method invoked? Is the Hibernate delete command invoked? Or if both are, you aren't seeing any changes in DB? If so, is the problem then *really* in the JSF side? E.g. when you use a different front-end technology such as a plain servlet class, or Spring MVC, or even a plain Java class with a `main()` method, does the Hibernate delete command then work? All in all, what I'm trying to hint, this problem is most likely unrelated to JSF, provided that there are no obvious mistakes made.

Comment: Hi Balus. Thanks for ur hint. When I click Delete commandLink, the IE will popup the information: Server Internal Error To reconnect click the Reload button on the browser or click the button below. Then, I found no error in log. Here is my JSF bean delete code:public String deleteActivityAction() throws P6Exception
  {

    adminService.deleteActivity((String[]) dataTable.getRowData());
    allActivities = adminService.findAllActivityTypes();
    return null;
}

Comment: Here is my DAO code:  public void deleteActivity(String[] activity) { AdminDaoImpl.logger.debug("delete activity in db"); this.getHibernateTemplate().delete(activity); }

Comment: Hi Balus. I think the issue is how I can get the Work_Type_Cd from the page, because the three columns in datatable comes from two different database tables. I need to get the Work_Type_Cd, and then delete the cascade two tables in DB. Do u know how to get Work_Type_Cd? Thanks!