# Delete datatable row in JSF

Tags: hibernate, jsf, jsf-2

I have a JSF data table, it has three columns, those three columns comes from two database tables. My question is how to get a specified row and delete it in DB.

1). Those three columns are just properties(not PK) in DB. if I just use `getRowData()`, I can just get these 3 properties from the page and cannot get the DB id, thus, cannot just call `this.getHibernateTemplate.delete();` to delete it.

2)Those two db table have one to many relationship. You can get the details from here:

[Delete JSF Datatable row(columns in row from different database)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541993/delete-jsf-datatable-rowcolumns-in-row-from-different-database)

Do you know how to implement it? Thanks!

Comment: When loading the data from the DB, you will as well load the PK with the other data to be displayed. After you displayed it and some row(s) got selected, you will have the PK. (even though I don't know how you can display the data of two tables with a 1:N relationship in 1 table.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I just load the 3 columns from two DB tables that I need as List<String[]>, and showed it in data table as activityAndWorkType[0],activityAndWorkType[1],activityAndWorkType[2]. So, if I need to select a row and delete it, just call getRowData? Can this method get PK together with the three showed columns? Thanks!

Comment: All your questions concerning this topic are pretty much overloaded with a lot of very specific details which make your questions actually just harder to understand. You should abstract a bit from your actual code, since most of the information is just not needed here. I assume you iterate a `dataTable` over some Collection. I think it was `List<ActivityType>`. So in case that you have the PK in your `ActivityType`, then your getRowData will return an `ActivityType` and you can easily access and delete it from the DB this way.

Comment: I don't understand why you complicate yourself. Just use a `<h:commandLink action="#{bean.delete(theRow)}">` where `theRow` is the element you use to iterate your list i.e. `<h:dataTable value="#{bean.theData}" var="theRow">`. Then in your `Bean#delete(String[] row)` you will have the necessary data to fetch the element you want/need to delete. The fact you use Hibernate or another ORM framework or another mechanism to interact with your database is a different story.